# ASP.NET MVC : join other site from http

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a trouble, my main website is : *http://www.mywebsite.com*

Some file are on another hosting service and other domaine : *http://www.mysecondweb.com*

I create the URL like this :

```
String.Format("<a href=\"www.mysecondweb.com/Files/{0}/{1}\">D/L</a>", path, file)
```

When I click on the link, I have this
*mywebsite.com/www.mysecondweb.com/Files/ThePath/File.txt*

I'd like to have this :
*www.mysecondweb.com/Files/ThePath/File.txt*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link should begin with `http://` so that it's obvious to the browser that the resource is on a different domain.